# iPhone: How to Sort Dates Using NSDate?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I have to sort objects based on NSDates. What are the options for sorting by NSDate?

Comment: How are the orders stored? NSArray? Do you have an NSArrayController, etc...

Answer (score 1):

In general you use a [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSortDescriptor) to define the sort of collections like arrays or Core Data. You call the sort from the collection object itself.

NSDate itself has comparison functions if you want to do the sort directly yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do sorting of date by comparing two dates.For that you should use. NSComparisonResult class. 
NSComparisonResult result=[date1 compare:date2];

if result==NSorderSame
  then date1 and date2 is Same.

result==NSOrderedAscending
  then date1 is smaller than date2.

result==NSOrderedDescending
    then date1 is greater than date2.